# about setting up juju environment

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud

We are trying to setup **openstack** on a virtual environment-KVM(on a virtual machine where resources provided very well 12 gb ram, 500 gb hardisk, 6 processors). we were able to setup maas environment with **10 nodes**. We want to progress to next step and setup **juju** for putting components of openstack which are horizon,neutron, nova, keystone, cellometer, cinder etc.(rest of all modules)

My question do we need to setup juju just onto "**maas controller**" or do we need to setup juju for **each node**? I didn't understand this point very well...

Can you give me a clear explanation about this topic?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I tried to establish "juju environments" to the node where I have install maas controller node. Then when you try to power juju bootstrap, it randomly chooses one of the node where it gets ssh from maas envrionment that you have already provided. So bootstrap of juju is going to be absolutely another node after you run

```
juju bootstrap
```

then you can add machines to juju if you have in your maas environment and can 
deploy any service that you want which is the magic of juju.

Answer (score 1):

You install juju on the machine where you expect to drive the deployments from. It can even be more than one machine, and then you would share the environment file with other people.

It's kind of like installing openssh-client on the machines where you want to administer your network from. It's where you run ssh from. Same with juju. You will run the juju commands from some machine. It can be anywhere, as long as it can reach out to the nodes.